# Agregar caracteres a un string en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Tengo una cadena muy sencilla como la siguiente

> ' kyo,1,koko,yuyu '

entonces quisiera agregar le a cada palabra comillas simples para obtener algo como

> ' 'kyo','1','koko','yuyu' '

incluso de ser posible me gustaría respetar los valores enteros, me imagino que puedo separarlos por comas con **split** pero mi verdadera pregunta está en cómo puedo agregarle las comillas entre los comas y devolver todo en un solo string.
¿Alguna idea? Mil gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`REPLACE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
'''' + REPLACE('kyo,1,koko,yuyu', ',', ''',''') + ''''
```

Básicamente reemplazamos las `,` por otra cadena, en este caso por `','`. Tienes que tener en cuenta que para indicar literalmente una comilla simple hay que "escaparla" con dos comillas, es decir `''` -> `'`. Pero con esto solo contemplamos las comillas entre cadenas, nos faltaría la primer y última comilla que la agregamos concatenandolas.